# How do I pass the desired System.Random.Next overload to my F# function?

Tags: function, f#

Just getting started with F#. Could someone please tell me why I cannot pass the Next overload that takes two `int` parameters and returns an `int` to my `printNext` function? As far as I can tell the types are lining up... but that's not what the compiler says.

```
open System

let r = new Random()

let printNext (nextInt : int -> int -> int) =

    let i = nextInt 0 100

    printf "%d" i

let t x y = x + y

// compiles fine
printNext t

// compilation error
printNext r.Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is, that your `printNext` function takes a parameter of type `int -> int -> int`, but the `Random.Next` method has type `int * int -> int`. I.e. you expect a function taking [curried](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/) parameters, but provide a function taking tupled parameters.

The issue is *not* that the compiler can't find the correct overloaded method, but rather that there is no overloaded `Random.Next` method taking curried parameters.

This all might seem confusing, and it does take a bit of getting used to, but currying is a pretty sweet tool when you get to know it. For instance, it allows for [partial application](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/). An issue, when coming to F#, is that a method such as `Random.Next` was initially designed for consumption by C#, and does hence not have curried parameters.

**Update:** I forgot the actual solution to your issue, which @3615 has provided. I'll add it here for completion, not to take anything from @3615's answer.

The solution in this case is to write a wrapper around the `Random.Next` method. If you'll be using it multiple times, you can put it in a variable - otherwise just use an anonymous function. Either of the following will work

```
let nextRnd x y = r.Next(x, y)
printNext nextRnd

printNext (fun  x y-> r.Next(x,y))
```

Comment: Great explanation, I was missing the fact that Next got tupled params.

Answer (score 2):

In this case F# compiler seems not to be able to deduce that you need an overload with 2 parameters and it picks the overload with one parameter. So to work around it you could wrap that method like this: `printNext (fun  x y-> r.Next(x,y))`